# How get a collision point with SAT

Tags: collision-detection, game-development, separating-axis-theorem

I have implemented SAT collision detection system in 2D , but I don't get how get a collision impact point.

For the moment I obtain the mtv and the separating axis, so I can resolve the collision but not apply correct forces on it, because impact point is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A response here https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/588070-seperating-axis-theorem---how-to-resolve-contact-points/
from Dirk Gregorius, helped me to resolve the problem.
As described you have to found the two edge closest and watch where they collide, if not it means it's edge/edge collision
The " first" face is the esaier one, because it's the one perpendicular to your seprating axis. For the other face I choose to make a dot a product of my first face with all other edges and found the one with the less dot product. Then I check if the two segment collide.